# Remove stranger alphabets characters from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to load suggestions from user input, but my query fails if user enters some stanger alphabets characters (chinese, greek...).

```
$alphaAccent =    array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ð', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ű', 'ý', 'ÿ');
    $str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-'.implode($alphaAccent).']/', '', $str); // Removes special chars.
```

It looks like `preg_replace` does not check for this kind of characters, and puts � character in `$str` instead.

Any hint on this?

Comment: You need the `/u` modifier - https://ideone.com/kz8RBh

Comment: Any feedback? Are you sure your source files are in UTF8 encoding?

Comment: Well it seems to work actually. I wasn't sure because I did have other actions afterwards who changed my string, but that made it. Thanks!

Comment: I see, I posted an answer. Please consider accepting since it worked for you and upvoting if it turned out helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the [`/u` UNICODE modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to the regex so that it could match the

```
$alphaAccent = array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ð', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ű', 'ý', 'ÿ');
$str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-'.implode($alphaAccent).']/u', '', $str);
```

In short, it makes the pattern Unicode aware and makes PHP treat the string as a Unicode string.